# Placing a tikz picture and tabular side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I'm trying to place a a simple table and a tikz image side by side. It doesn't seem to be working at all and they get stacked on top of eachother.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A1) at (0,0) {$A_1$};
\node[draw] (A2) at (1.5,0) {$A_2$};
\node[draw] (A3) at (3,0) {$A_3$};

\draw[->] (A1) to (A2);
\draw[bend left, ->] (A2) to (A3);
\draw[bend left, ->] (A3) to (A2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l | c c c}
\toprule
 Attacking/Attacked & $A_1$  & $A_2$  & $A_3$ \\ \midrule
 $A_1$  & 0  & 1 & 0 \\
 $A_2$  & 0  & 0 & 1 \\
 $A_3$  & 0  & 1 & 0 \\
 \toprule
 $\sum Attacked$  & 0  & 2 & 1 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Some matrix}   
\label{graph:exampleMatrix}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I've tried using minipage, but my image gets stacked.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your question is for sure duplicate to many similar questions. Some of them are listed on the right site of your question. And please, complete your code sniped to full document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Help us to help you.

Comment: first, @Zarko's comment is solid.  however, a quick observation directed at the fact that the `tikzpicture` and `tabular` are stacked: the blank line between them is equivalent to `\par`, hence a directive to stack them.  replace that by `\hfil` and that will cause them to be interpreted as on the same line.

Comment: Hi Zarko. Thanks for your response. I have read through all teh duplicates I could find, and that is were I learnt of 'minipage' yet my code does not seem to be working. Apologies I am new to the group and quite new to Latex to

Comment: Hello Barbara.. I have tested that out as well, yet it remains stacked

Comment: Also comment the line ending at the end of the first `\end{minipage}`. Otherwise, the content is too wide for the page and TeX has to stack them. You don't need `\noindent` with `\centering`.

Comment: Hi Barbara...Apologies is was some strange issue with my distribution / install of Mactex because your fix works when I paste my code into overleaf...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use `tabular` environment instead of `minipages`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells 
    \setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}   
    \setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{c@{\qquad}c}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A1) at (0,0) {$A_1$};
\node[draw] (A2) at (1.5,0) {$A_2$};
\node[draw] (A3) at (3,0) {$A_3$};
%
\draw[->] (A1) to (A2);
\draw[bend left, ->] (A2) to (A3);
\draw[bend left, ->] (A3) to (A2);
\end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \begin{tabular}{l | c c c }
    \toprule
Attacking/Attacked  & $A_1$ & $A_2$ & $A_3$ \\ \midrule
 $A_1$              & 0     & 1     & 0     \\
 $A_2$              & 0     & 0     & 1     \\
 $A_3$              & 0     & 1     & 0     \\
 \toprule
 $\sum Attacked$    & 0     & 2     & 1     \\
 \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some matrix}
    \label{graph:exampleMatrix}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For vertical space in cells I add macro `\makegapedcells`, set gabs to `5pt` and remove vertical spaces around rules from `booktabs`.

[image]